# Looking for generating function of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{1-x^k}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Wondering if anyone knows how to find a generating function or a nice clean formula for

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} { {n}\choose{k} } (a^k \bmod q)$$

Multiplying by $x^n$ and summing over $n$ gives the below as a generating function, maybe there is a simple form for this?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{1-x^k}.$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^k = (1+a)^n$ without the need for all that. Also $\frac{a^k}{1-x^k}$ is no good when $k=0$.

Comment: Let $f(a,q) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} { {n}\choose{k} } (a^k \bmod q)$. Apparently, some special cases are $f(2,3)=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$, $f(2,4)=2n+1$, $f(2,6)=3\cdot 2^n-3$, $f(2,8)=2n^2+1$, $f(2,16)= (4n^3-6n^2+8n+3)/3$, $f(3,4)=2^{n+1}$, $f(3,6)=3\cdot 2^n-2$, $f(3,9)=3n+1$, $f(3,27)=(9n^2-3n+2)/2$.

Comment: @BillyJoe Yes, thank you. It has a surprising amount of structure

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235604/573047) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74033/573047) found with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%5Ek%7D%7B1-x%5Ek%7D.%24&p=6).

Comment: See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759478/573047). After reading the answer there, I conjecture that your sequence satisfies a recurrence $a(n)=2(m \bmod 2)a(n-m)+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{m \choose k}(-1)^{k+1}a(n-k)$ where $m=ord_{q}(a)$.